# Memory leaks in MFC application with threads

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11

Could anyone help with a memory leaks in a MFC application? The program seems to work fine without the following code block. The block includes conditional execution of several tasks and passage of data to MFC dialog data members, then indicators on the MFC dialog are updated. Other tests show everything works normal, except there are memory leak messages in the debug window. Platform: WIN 7 64bit, MSVC 2011. Thanks!

```
#include <vector>
#include <thread> 

//Implementation parallel tasking
void CMASTERDlg::OnCompositeParalleltasking()
{   
const int totTsk=8;
BOOL select[totTsk]={
    m_Parallel_Audio,
    m_Parallel_DDS,
    m_Parallel_HV,
    m_Parallel_Monitor,
    m_Parallel_PDA,
    m_Parallel_Pulnix,
    m_Parallel_Supertime,
    m_Parallel_Temp};

//Put all selected tasks in a thread vector
std::vector<std::thread> threads;
auto pvThread = threads.begin(); 

if (m_Parallel_Audio)
    threads.push_back(std::thread(Audio, 1));
if (m_Parallel_DDS) 
    threads.push_back(std::thread(DDS, 1, 1));
if (m_Parallel_HV) 
    threads.push_back(std::thread(HVgetShow, this, 3));
if (m_Parallel_Monitor) 
    threads.push_back(std::thread(MonitorgetShow, this));
if (m_Parallel_PDA) 
    threads.push_back(std::thread(PDAgetShow, this));
if (m_Parallel_Pulnix) 
    threads.push_back(std::thread(DoNothing, 1));
if (m_Parallel_Supertime) 
    threads.push_back(std::thread(MMCS,Sequence_id, static_cast<LPCSTR>(CStringA(loopnum))));
if (m_Parallel_Temp) 
    threads.push_back(std::thread(TempgetShow,this));

pvThread = threads.begin();
while (pvThread != threads.end())
{
     pvThread->join();
     pvThread++;
}

//update data on front panel
UpdateData(FALSE);
UpdateWindow();


//count selected tasks and output message
int j=0, count=0;
for(j=0; j<totTsk; j++) {
   if (select[j])  count++;
}
char buffer[2];
itoa (count,buffer,10);
string message=string(buffer)+" tasks completed in parallel\n";
TRACE(message.c_str());  //Message in debugging window

}
```

Comment: There doesn't appear to be any memory allocations in the posted code, so the memory leak is almost certainly happening in one of the functions run by one of the threads you started.

Comment: @ChadThanks Chad. I tested the code with just one thread and a simple do-nothing function as below and saw similar memory leak, that made me wondering if I had any settings wrong.  It was also strange that I had a message at the end of the implementation, which popes out earlier than expected.                                                                                                        void DoNothing() //test function
{
 //do nothing 
}

Comment: It just looks like the thread I added has conflicts with threads for MFC dialog. BTW, the code block can run under a non-GUI project just fine.

Answer (score 0):

The code

```
pvThread = threads.begin();
while (pvThread != threads.end())
{
     pvThread->join();
     pvThread++;
}
```

seems questionable to me. The first time into this loop, the current thread (which I assume is the main application UI thread) will block when it calls join() on the first thread, until that thread completes.  If the first thread takes longer than at least some of the other threads, then eventually you'll find yourself calling join() on a defunct thread.  Perhaps the system is leaking something while handling this?

Comment: Thank you pnswdv. This seems very likely to the problem. Do you have a hint that may solve this? Detected memory leaks!
Dumping objects ->
{389} normal block at 0x00631518, 56 bytes long.
 Data: <                > 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
Object dump complete.

Comment: In case anyone is interested, the above problem is solved with AfxBeginThread from MFC library, rather than using threads directly.